# Remove Top Line of Text File with PowerShell - but only if it's blank

Tags: powershell

I know that I can use:

Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object { (get-Content $*) | Where-Object {(1) -notcontains $*.ReadCount } | Set-Content -path $_ }

to remove the first line of a file, but I only want to do this if the line is blank or starts with a space.

I've tried various options including:
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object { (get-Content $*) | Where-Object {(1) -ne " "} | Set-Content -path $* }
(I feel like the key to this is in the Where-Object statement) - but my PS is not great.

There seem to be a lot of posts about deleting all blank lines, but nothing about only the first conditionally.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)? Thanks in advance. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough actually:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | 
ForEach-Object {
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName
    if ($Content[0] -match '^\s|^$' ) {
        $NewContent = @($Content[1..($Content.Count - 1)] ) -join "`r`n"
        [system.io.file]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, $NewContent,[text.encoding]::UTF8)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that solved the problem nicely.

Comment: Cool ... glad to hear that it helped. 

Comment: It has - very much. One thing I had not considered though is that Set-Content adds a CR at the end of the file (which is okay for most of them, but I have a few that it creates an issue for when pushing them through an API). I know about the -NoNewLine switch, but if I add that, then the whole file appears to get truncated to a single line in an editor. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: Hmm ... that's a tricky one since all built in PowerShell cmdlets seem to produce this empty last line.  On the other hand I'd expect any API or tool ingnoring an empty last line. ‍♂️ However, using a .NET  class seems to do the trick. Try!

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I am almost there. This works perfectly for 95% of the files I'm working with. I have a few hundred pdf files that I need to run the same operation on, but the UTF8 encoding seems to corrupt them. They need to be encoded in ASCII, but the combinations I'm trying don't seem to work.

Comment: I'd expect this *solution* only working for plain text files like `*.txt` or `*.log` or even `*.ps1` but not for binary formats like `*.pdf`. For binary file formats you need to use their according executable to manipulate their content. BTW: You still should fix the formatting of the code in your question. Please read the help topic I mentioned in my first comment above. 

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-ChildItem *.txt) | ForEach{
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace '^\s[^\n\r]*[\n\r]{1,2}' | Set-ConTent $_.FullName -NoNewLine
}
```

I had mis-read *...blank or starts with a space...* as *...blank or is a space...*

You could also have a straight pipeline by wrapping the replacemetn operation in a Filter and using a pipeline variable:

```
Filter StripSelected {
    $_ -replace '^\s[^\n\r]*[\n\r]{1,2}'
}

Get-ChildItem *.txt -pv pvFileInfo |
  Get-Content -Raw | StripSelected |
Set-ConTent $pvFileInfo.FullName -NoNewLine
```

Comment: That's what I get for posting from my phone. Will correct when I get home to computer..

Comment: Of course I saw that, but there's always a hundred-and-one ways to do things in **PowerShell**, and always good to see alternate approaches.

Comment: Corrected code posted

Comment: Neat. 

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way using a [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-8.0) to avoid reading the content of all files when there may not be needed.

```bash
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        # open a StreamReader
        $reader = $_.OpenText()

        # if the first line matches any non whitespace character
        if ($reader.ReadLine() -match '\S') {
            # go to the next file
            return
        }

        # else, read all content (skipping the first line)
        $content = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
        return
    }
    finally {
        if ($reader) {
            # dispose the reader
            $reader.Dispose()
        }
    }

    # and write back to the file
    $content | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code shown is the question is not valid PowerShell code. This code will iterate over the files identified by `Get-ChildItem`, determine if the first line meets the criteria using `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, then set the number of lines to skip appropriately.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\WW*.TXT |
    ForEach-Object {
        $FirstLine = Get-Content -Path $_ -First 1
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($FirstLine)) {
            (Get-Content -Path $_) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Path $_
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure with the parameter `-First` for `Get-Content`?  

Comment: @Olaf, `-First` and `-Head` are aliases of `-TotalCount`.

Comment: Ui ... learned something new today. Thanks.   I just prefer not to use aliasses. ‍♂️

Comment: Parameter aliases are not the same as command aliases. The parameter alias is a full, understandable word. That's a lot different than using `cgi` or `gc`.

Comment: You're perfectly right.  And I'm not complaining at all. I just said that I prefer not to use them. ‍♂️ I just took a quick look to the docu for the parameters for `Get-Content` and didn't see them at first in the list of paramters. Only when you pointed me to it.